# Add AppCompat dependency to Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-appcompat

Verdant newbie here. I'm making a fairly simple project that needs to be compatible with Android versions older than Lollipop, but still want to have the app look nicer by using `AppCompat`.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to work (or even find) the gradle - I tried to run a gradle task: `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"`

But it returned an error saying that "*Task 'compile' is ambiguous....*" in my project.

Could anyone tell me how to add this? I've searched all over Google, but everything goes way over my head.

Thanks!

Comment: paste your gradle file here to locate the ambiguous statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you been able to locate Gradle file?

Edit your gradle like this :

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xyz.xyz"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.00.00"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
}
```

Update your question and post full Gradle code.

[image: You can find Gradle file here]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was trying with the wrong build.gradle. A few attempts, I got it working!

Comment: Great to hear! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Add the appcomapt library(com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+") in dependancy section of the build.gradle file

[image]

Or second way to add library is by searching on maven repo.this can be done by traversing file->project structure->app>dependancy->click (+) ->add Library dependancy

Answer (score 0):

> Task 'compile' is ambiguous.

This issue is not the Compile Issue. but this was an issue on the `task` itself.

if you are not using a command like `"gradle compileDebug"` then one of the android configurations are executing the task and it is not working well with your build.gradle.

Here is a link that seems to relate specifically to your issue. [Click Here](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/android-app-has-error-execution-failed-taskapppredexdebug-trying-to-test-parse-but-cant-run-app-with-this-error)